# targeting an iframe with js getElementById for arrow navigation

Tags: javascript, iframe, navigation, getelementbyid, arrow-keys

I've seen a number of very similar questions but they don't seem to deal with the particular situation I have, but feel free to just point me to one of them should I have missed it.

I have a website that uses an iframe to display content html (from the same domain). I have back and next buttons in the iframe content html to allow seeing the prev/next content without having to close the iframe to pick the prev/next. What I **want** to do is add arrow key functionality to this so they can go to the prev/next content page just by keyboard. I managed to get this working on the content html, but it works only when the content html is loaded by itself in a new tab - but it fails as an iframe. I'm assuming I have a targeting issue here. *Ideally* I want this functionality only when the iframe is open, but I'm flexible if it needs to go into the root html.

Here's what I have:
JS-arrowsprevnext.js

```
   var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
   switch(key){
      //left arrow
      case 37:
         document.getElementById("prevLink").click();
      break;
      //right arrow
      case 39:
         document.getElementById("nextLink").click();
      break;
   }
});
```

Main Html:

```
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_SaurianTerrain.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_Saurian01.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_SaurianBiomes.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_Saurian02.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_DinosaurValley.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_FallOfTheDinosaurs_med.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_Halo5_01.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_Halo501.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_LastSentinel.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_LastSentinel.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_Murdered.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_Murdered02.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_VictorianHouse.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_VictorianHouse.jpg"></a>
<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_AnimalSketches.html"><img class="image" src="img/TH_SketchAnimals01a.jpg"></a>
```

iframe Html:

```
<script src="js/arrowsprevnext.js"></script>
...
...
...
<a id="prevLink" href="portfolio_DinosaurValley.html"><img src="img/prev.png"></a>
```

And just for more history, I found a pre-made script (lightbox) for an iframe with arrow navigation that works for single images (which I'm using for most of my site). And I found another script (colorbox) that does lots of things into an iframe, but can't do arrow navigation with the html into an iframe.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `.click();` I assume you're using jQuery here?

Comment: i think so, but tbh i'm not sure

Comment: While I want something elegant (arrow keys go to the iframe, find the id 'prev' or 'next' and execute whatever link associated there), I could imagine something more complex that resides in the index.html (since i know the code works there), but it would probably have to incorporate a variable to keep track of what page the iframe is currently showing, and some way to prevent things from firing off when the iframe isn't up. not ideal (esp as it's almost certianly beyond my ability), but if it works....

Comment: UPDATE: my code works, but only after i click somewhere in the iframe first

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was that the iframe didn't have focus on creation. so far, i'm solving it like most other ppl - adding a button at the top:
            `button id="focalpoint" "x"<"/button">`
and adding that id to the called url:
`<a class='iframe' id="portfolioframe" href="portfolio_Halo5_01.html#focalpoint"><img class="image" src="img/TH_Halo501.jpg"></a>`

I tried adding a div id to the url, but that didn't work for some reason, so i'll stick with a 1px button w. an id.